# Django model organization: food item locations in different grocery stores

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a cookbook app and I want to sort the ingredients of a recipe by their aisle in the grocery store. Since different grocery stores have different configurations, I want users to be able to sort the lists of ingredients by a selected store. I'm new to Django and am stuck on figuring out the models that I'll need for this. I think I want to have a many to many relationship between my `Food` model and a `Store` model. I think I want to use the `through` argument and have another intermediary `Location` model that connects the 'Food' and 'Store' and also contains which the `aisle`.

If possible, I'd like to have the `choices` for `aisle` have a certain description that depends on the selection of the `Store` object

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grocery_aisle = models.ManytoManyField(Store, through='Location')

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    aisles = { # Not really sure how to store this kind of information which would be different for each Store object.
        0: 'Produce Section',
        1: 'Aisle 1: bread and peanutbutter',
        2: 'Frozen Desserts',
        3: 'Pharmacy'
    }

class Location(models.Model):
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    aisle = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=MEASUREMENT_CHOICES) # option descriptions depend on selected store object
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I like Django a lot so far, but this is my first time using it, so I'm fumbling a bit.

Comment: you can try [choiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) but unfortunately problem is not too clear to me. Can you please tell what you actually looking for, design ?

Comment: I'm trying to have several configurations of `Aisle`s (a `Store`) that each contain `Food` objects. Then I want to take a list of `Food` objects and order them based on what aisle they are on. I want the order to change depending on different `Store` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It'll allow you to store multiple `Aisle`s within a `Store`, then assign every `Food` to multiple `Aisle`s using a many-to-many relationship.

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Aisle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    aisle = models.ManytoManyField(Aisle)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    food = models.ManyToManyField(Food)

    def find_in_store(self, store):
        """
        Write a method here that finds a given recipe in a store, and call it with recipe.find_in_store(store). This will be a bit of a complex function, but a naive implementation (if you are running a small-scale project) would be to loop through all Aisle objects in the given store and determine whether any Food objects needed for the Recipe can be found in the given Aisle.
         """
```

Comment: This seems to make sense to me. Can you help me understand how I would sort a list of `Food`s by aisle for a given store? I've added `location = models.IntegerField(help_text="0 starts on one side of the store and increments moving to the other")` to the Aisle model to order the aisles within a single store.

Comment: Like this: First, get a store: `store = Store.objects.all()[0]` then, filter for food within an aisle in that store and order by location: `Food.objects.filter(aisle__store=store).order_by(aisle__location)`

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to sort out an edge case now. My understanding is that `.filter(aisle__store=store)` will return all `Food` objects that have an attribute `aisle` which has a `store` attribute equal to `store` of my choosing. Each of those `Food` objects can still have multiple `aisle` attributes (for each store that sells the food item). When I do `.order_by(aisle__location)`, which `aisle` will Django use for the ordering? Since a `Food` object can have multiple `aisle`s, this seems ambiguous.

Comment: Oops! I advised you incorrectly in my previous comment — my apologies. Try the following. First, get a store: `store = Store.objects.all()[0]`. Then, filter for aisles within that store: `aisles = Aisle.objects.filter(store=store)`. You now have a list of all aisles in the given store. Now you can pull a list of all foods within those aisles: `Food.objects.filter(aisle__in=aisles)`. Unfortunately, ordering this list of foods is non-trivial, but you may not have to depending on what you want to do. Could you iterate through `Aisle`s to accomplish your goal?

Comment: The use case I'm working towards is starting with a group of `Food` objects (the ingredients to a recipe). Then I want to sort them by `aisle` for a specific `Store`. If I'm iterating through `Aisle`s, I'm not quite sure how to print out only the `Food`s that are a part of the `Recipe`.

Comment: You should add a Recipe class that has a many-to-many relationship with Food. Then define a method within the Recipe class that shops for the given Recipe within a Store. I've updated my answer above with an example.